# Jquery Load function only working every other time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement this code: 
http://www.dba-resources.com/scripting-programming/ajax-tabs-in-bootstrap-2-1/

Which adds ajax loading functionally, I'm using Twitter Bootstrap which doesn't have this built in.

Everything works fine but it seems every other time you press a tab the content doesn't load. So I can press "Contact" And this loads fine. However when I press "Contact Log" the tabs change to indicate I'm now on Contact Log but the content doesn't load in (the content from the last tabs is still there). If I then pressed the next tab that content would load in correctly.

I've checked and it seems the second time around nothing is being returned via the load function I'm just getting an empty object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MainTabs").tab();
    $("#MainTabs").bind("show", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);
        var contentID = $(e.target).attr("data-target");
        var contentURL = $(e.target).attr("href");
        if (typeof (contentURL) != "undefined") {
            console.log(contentID);
            console.log(contentURL);
            console.log($(contentID).load(contentURL));
            $(contentID).load(contentURL, function () {
                $("#MainTabs").tab();
            });
        } else {
            $(contentID).tab("show");
        }
    });
    $("#MainTabs a:first").tab("show");
});
```

```
<div class="span12">
<ul id="MainTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a data-target="#general" data-toggle="tab" title="General">General</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#contacts" data-toggle="tab" href="/manager/contacts/VkdVPQ==/network_partner" title="Contacts">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#contactLog" data-toggle="tab" href="/manager/contactLog/VldRPQ==/network_partner" title="Contact Log">Contact Log</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#prohibitiveAdvertising" data-toggle="tab" href="/manager/prohibitiveAdvertising/QURFPQ==" title="Contact Log">Prohibitive Advertising</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#placements" data-toggle="tab" href="/manager/placements/VkdVPQ==" title="Placements">Placements</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#actionPoints" data-toggle="tab" href="/manager/actionPoints/Q0RrPQ==" title="Action Points">Action Points</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#repository" data-toggle="tab" href="/manager/repository/QVRBPQ==" title="Repository">Repository</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane" id="general">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="contacts">
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="contactsLog">
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="prohibitiveAdvertising">
</div>    
<div class="tab-pane" id="placement">  
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="actionPoints">    
</div>
<div class="tab-pane"id="repository">
</div>
</div>
```

I've used console.lo to check what the contactID and ContactURL and these always come back as what I would expect every time I click a tab.

Comment: A lot of times when you hear something works every other click that means you probably are attaching some property on the first click that the second click activates.

Comment: Thanks Kadumel, do you know how I could find out if that's the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if [this working example on Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/63891) helps you